# Can't find inline style displayed in inspect element in original html code

Tags: html, css

I am struggling with the CSS here. In Firefox's inspect element it shows the inline style as

`element {max-width: 400px;}`

but in the actual HTML file there is only

```
<ul>
```

I am attaching both of the screenshots

1. Screenshot from the Firefox's inspect element tool

[image: this is the inspect element screenshot]

2. Screenshot from the text editor.
   [image: this the HTML code from the text editor]

Comment: Inline style could also be applied via javascript.

Comment: are you using some frontend js frame work that programmatically sets the max-width?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -2):

You should add the entire HTML and CSS.

The `max-width` could also be set by the parent's style.

Also, I think you misunderstand the concept of inline style, as you showed us the CSS and not the HTML seen in the Element Inspector.